# CORS issue even with origin policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have some fonts hosted on AWS Cloudfront behind a custom domain. 

I have this as s3 CORS policy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*.dabster.io</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>dabster.io</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

on Cloudfront Behaviours I have following settings

- Viewer Protocol Policy : HTTP and HTTPS
- Allowed HTTP Methods : GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
- Forward Headers : Whitelist

  - Access-Control-Request-Headers
  - Access-Control-Request-Method
  - Origin

The error I am getting is

> Access to Font at
>   'https://cdn.dabster.io/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0'
>   from origin 'https://dabster.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://dabster.io' is therefore not allowed access.

You can see the error at https://dabster.io and https://www.dabster.io

```
curl -I -s -X GET -H "Origin: dabster.io" https://cdn.dabster.io/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf\?v\=4.7.0                                 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 165548
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sun, 07 May 2017 09:26:57 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: dabster.io
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Last-Modified: Fri, 05 May 2017 14:04:16 GMT
ETag: "b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Origin,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 d674762e43fd40650eec6e201e4316a2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: JYxW4fs2Ijgt_wEnl-DQ6Yqz_qPYbwaWZSZyRjrnKQ_yje__n3skkA==
```

I am also getting the headers in the response.
Please shed some light on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An origin value must include a protocol part—`https://` or `http://`. So you need to do this:

```
<AllowedOrigin>https://dabster.io</AllowedOrigin>
```

The reason your `curl` test works is that you’re sending the `Origin` header with no protocol part.

But browsers send an `Origin` header with the protocol part; e.g., `Origin: https://dabster.io`.

So as you currently have things configured, your `curl` test will fail too if you include the protocol:

```
curl -I -s -X GET -H "Origin: https://dabster.io" \
  https://cdn.dabster.io/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf\?v\=4.7.0
```

Comment: ok let me try this and see if it works, ill update accordingly

Comment: I have made changes and invalidated the cloudfront cache, but as for curl it works with protocol as well.

Comment: If you made the `<AllowedOrigin>https://dabster.io</AllowedOrigin>` config change, then it’s expected that the curl test will now work if you specify the protocol. But are you still getting the “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present” error in your browser devtools console? Or is your web app able to get the font as expected now?